# How to make query in junction table in a many-to-many scenario where you want to regroup

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm struggling to find a proper solution for the following problem:

I have a table for matches, that represent a game match, a match is always composed of 5 players. I have a table for players, each row is a player, representing a real person. I have a junction table between the two as they behave in a Many-To-Many pattern. match_player link the concept of a specific match to a player.

Now I need help building a SQL query. Given that I know the identity of 5 specific players, I would like to list all matches where those 5 players played together.

Can you help?

Some reference to help visualize:

```
table: player
  - id

table: match
  - id

table: match_player:
  - id
  - player_id
  - match_id
```

Considering I have players with id (1, 5, 9, 11 and 23), I would like to know all the matches they played together.

I can easily get it to work by retrieving everything then iterating on the data, but ideally I would like to not have to do post-processing, hopefully a query can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select mp.match_id
from match_player mp
where player_id in (1, 5, 9, 11, 23)
group by mp.match_id
having count(*) = 5;
```

This assumes that players are not listed multiple times in the same match.  If that is possible, use `count(distinct player_id)` for the `having` clause.

Comment: Your query didn't work directly but you got me on the right path to make it work. Ultimately the query that worked looked like this:

SELECT match_player.match_id, COUNT(match_player.player_id)
FROM match_player
WHERE match_player.player_id in (1,5,9,11,23)
GROUP BY match_player.match_id
HAVING COUNT(match_player.player_id) = 5;

I thank you very much for your time and effort in helping me with my issue. Have a good day Gordon.